# Docker toolbox Xdebug not working with PhpStorm

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I tried all the tutorials I found on the internet and still can't use a simple break point in PhpStorm using docker toolbox...

I currently have this inside my `Dockerfile`:

```
# Install xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    echo "error_reporting = E_ALL" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_startup_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "display_errors = On" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_port=9001" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_host=192.168.99.100" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini; \
    echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini;
```

Xdebug gets installed and configured correctly (`php -i` output):

```
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 192.168.99.100 => 192.168.99.100
xdebug.remote_log => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9001 => 9001
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
```

In my PhpStorm configuration I have the following:

Proxy:

[image: DBGp Proxy]

Debug
[image: Debug]

PHP interpreter
[image: PHP interpreter]

Debug config
[image: Debug config]

Server configuration
[image: Server config]

The blurred items are `Username` and `project name`.

I have 2 folders in a project, one called `docker` and holds all the docker files and one `site`, that holds all the site files.

The configuration for my docker-compose is the following:

```
version: '3'

services:
  application:
    image: project_image:latest
    environment:
      - C_UID=${C_UID:-1000}
      - C_GID=${G_UID:-1000}
      - DEVELOPMENT=${DEVELOPMENT:-1}
      - ~/.ssh:/var/www/.ssh
      - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ${APPLICATION:-../site}:/phpapp
    ports:
      - 9001:9001

  nginx:
    image: dockerwest/nginx-laravel:${NGINXVERSION:-stable}
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${BASEHOST:-project_name.docker},${EXTRAHOSTS}
    volumes:
      - ${APPLICATION:-../site}:/phpapp
    links:
      - application
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Anyone a clue on what I'm doing wrong here?

When I try to de `telnet 192.168.99.100 9001`, the connection can't be made, port `9000`, neither, but port `80` gives me a good response.

Anyone who has an idea what's going on here?

Comment: is phpstorm running AND listening ?   top bar, phone.

Comment: Yes, here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/1vKFRmG.png

Comment: `192.168.99.100` where it came from? 0_o

Comment: @myxaxa that's the IP I get from the VM that docker toolbox (windows) gives me.

Comment: That's the wrong address than, as I explained in the answer.

Comment: Look at the ports -- you are exposing Xdebug port 9001 in Docker, which tells "I'm using this port for my container". Now IDE is unable to listen on that port .. as it's Xdebug that connects t IDE and NOT other way around. Check the basic on how Xdebug works here to have a better understanding what you are doing wrong: https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xdebug needs to open a connection **to** PhpStorm. You don't need the ports exposed in Docker, or do anything with the Xdebug proxy. The telnet needs to be done from within your docker container to PhpStorm. The IP address in `xdebug.remote_host`, needs to be the IP address of your IDE, and not the IP address of your docker container (where HTTP/Apache listens on port 80).

Comment: Okay, I'm with you, but how do I know the IP of my IDE? That's nbot the IP in the network right? (172.16.199.69 in my case now)?

Comment: @Robin `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal` try this

Comment: `php -i` gives me `xdebug.remote_host => 192.168.99.100 => host.docker.internal` now, but the debugging still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

3 conditions must be fulfilled for xdebug to work remotely with VirtualBox, I had it especially in connection with Docker inside virtualbox.

**1)** remote_connect_back=1 or the exact ip address of your host machine (which can differ often) must be listed in the remote_host config field (, sometimes both at the same time don't work together, especially in the case of a docker being separately from a virtualbox = at windows hyper-v directly)

**2)** no other application like eg. a web-project can be exposed at the port 9000, that must be reserved for the php editor, or a different port must be reserved by the editor/listened at (or for the php web project), and addressed/transmitted to from the php, it is a project-based configuration

**3)** it's similar to the second point, VirtualBox must have no port forwarding to that port, as it would effectively occupy it but it must be reserved for the php editor, not for virtualbox port forwarding. Not virtualbox has to listen at that port to be forwarded to some internal app, but the outer php-editor has to listen for it=that port

Comment: Connect back inside virtualbox docker will work only for web, not for console as of course web and php editor are at different place - outside of Virtualbox, whereas command line is inside Virtualbox. For the same reason it will not work for host.docker.internal for this setup as it refers to the immediate network behind docker nor the docker.for.mac.host.internal or docker.for.win.localhost as in this case phpeditor is outside of Virtualbox whereas docker is inside. XDEBUG_CONFIG env var might be overriding any of connect_back or remote_host so it seems one of them worked and vice versa

Comment: XDEBUG_CONFIG env var seems not to work for every xdebug version/configuration

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth emphasizing that is it either xdebug.remote_host OR xdebug.remote_autostart. This is mentioned both in [the docs](https://2.xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back) and the [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60500925/revisions).

In other words - If you are having the feeling that your remote_host setting is being ignored, check if remote_autostart is not accidentally turned on.